# Align 2 divs side by side in a parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 div side by side with style "col2".
I would like to align these 2 div horizontally.
Today when i have only one column, i works fine, but when i put 2 div side by side, the divs are not centered.

**IMG**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="secondGroup">
    <div class="col2">
        <p class="titleSection">test 1</p>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <p class="titleSection">test 2</p>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.secondGroup {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 46.3%;
    height: 350px;
    background: white;
}

.col2:last-child {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.col2 .title {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make the parent, `.secondGroup`, a flex box with the `display:flex;` property and remove the float properties from the children.

```css
.secondGroup {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
    display:flex;
}

.col2 {
    width: 46.3%;
    height: 350px;
    background: white;
}

.col2:last-child {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.col2 .title {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondGroup">
    <div class="col2">
        <p class="titleSection">test 1</p>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <p class="titleSection">test 2</p>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

```
float: left;
```

From      .col2 .title and your code is working also

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` and add `display: inline-block;` to `.col2` will make center.

```
.col2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46.3%;
    height: 350px;
    background: white;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc0cfm40/)**

Comment: I tried to remove float left and add inline-block, the divs are now centered but the second div on the right is not under the first div..

Comment: @wawanopoulos it is because of `.col2:last-child {
    margin-left: 40px;
}`

Comment: I remove `.col2:last-child` same result

Comment: @wawanopoulos actually what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Updated, use `display: inline-block`

```
.secondGroup {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.col2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46.3%;
    height: 350px;
    background: white;
}

.col2:last-child {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.col2 .title {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/cw5cojbo/5/

Comment: The result in jsfiddle is not centered in secondGroup div. Try to add a background color to the secondGroup and you will see that the 2 divs are not centered. Could you propose another solution please ?

Comment: Replace `float: left` to `display inline-block`,  don't get your means in comment of `ketan` about "the second div on the right is not under the first div..". Could you explain more?